# In reduce, previousValue becomes undefined when I add conditional lines inside that performs .some and inside it performs .includes

Tags: javascript, undefined, reduce

The prevValue becomes undefined, but when I remove the conditional lines (170) above undefined is gone.

But when I add the prevValue as condition in the line 173, it won't perform the line below anymore.

What I wanted is when a condition is meet, then I can push an item inside prevValue.

I have the whole example that we can examine here in codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-feather-t79kb6?file=/src/index.js

Sorry, I spent hours on this simple one yet time consuming for me. Your help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: you always have to return the accumalated value (prevValue) in the callback. Here, you are returning only in a certain condition. Simply `return prevValue` outside the if condition.

Comment: You're not returning `prevValue` if `filtered` is true.

Comment: @Jay Surya, thank you, since you correctly answered first. Can we please make this as "post answer" then I can mark it check?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the help centre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The returned value of the callback function becomes the new accumulated value, with every iteration.

So, if we are not updating it, we have to return the old value itself.

```js
arr.reduce((acc,item)=>{
  if(condition) return acc.concat(item);
  //else
  return acc; //-->should not miss this.
},[])
```

I think this eslint rule https://eslint.org/docs/rules/array-callback-return will help catch this type of issues early.